How to synchronize the state variable react
I am writing a component in ReactJS. The component shows the multiple card in 3 column. To show data in this card I have taken one state variable named data.
This state variable is set by 4 useEffect. Because the data is not from one single API. To show data in card required to have 4 APIs to consume. Now the issue is with the synchronisation of useEffect for the data variable.
Following is the code:
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import StudyMonitoringCard from '@components1/k8s/common/StudyMonitoringCard';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getUserSession } from '@lib/auth';
import apiMonitoring from '@api1/monitoring';
import Loader from '@components1/common/Loader';
import apiStudy from '@api1/Study';
import { ApplicationStats } from 'src/utils/common';

interface MonitorData {
  name: string;
  studyname: string;
  span_id: string;
  account_name: string;
  account_id: string;
  ready_pods: number;
  total_pods: number;
}

const Monitoring: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<ApplicationStats[]>([]);
  const [uniqueAcc, setUniqueAcc] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [completedRelay, setCompletedRelay] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [completedEvent, setCompleteEvent] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setErrorMessage('');
    setLoading(true);
    const user = getUserSession();
    apiMonitoring
      .listMonitoringWorkload(user.tenant?.id as string)
      .then((res) => {
        setLoading(false);
        const monitoring = res?.data?.data?.k8s_workloads_cloud_account_monitoring_v2?.rows;
        const error = res?.data.errors;
        if (monitoring && monitoring.length > 0) {
          const data = monitoring.map((m: MonitorData) => ({
            name: m.name,
            studyname: m.studyname,
            accountName: m.account_name,
            accountId: m.account_id,
            workloadId: m.span_id,
            nrequests: null,
            nerrors: null,
            nerrorscritical: null,
            nevents: null,
            neventscpu: null,
            neventsmemory: null,
            cpu: null,
            mem: null,
            latency: null,
            rtt: null,
            optimize: '-',
            readyPods: m.ready_pods,
            totalPods: m.total_pods,
          }));
          const uniqueAcc = [...new Set(data.filter((b: any) => b.accountId).map((item: any) => item.accountId))];
          setData(data);
          setUniqueAcc(uniqueAcc as string[]);
        } else if (error && error.length > 0) {
          setData([]);
          setErrorMessage('Failed to fetch Monitoring');
        } else {
          setData([]);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setLoading(false);
        setErrorMessage('Failed to fetch Monitoring');
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data == undefined || data.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (const value of uniqueAcc) {
      const applicationArray = data
        .filter((b: any) => b.accountId == value)
        .map((b: any) => ({
          name: b.name,
          studyname: b.studyname,
        }));
      const request = {
        no_sinks: true,
        body: {
          account_id: value,
          action_name: 'application_stats',
          action_params: { applications: JSON.stringify(applicationArray) },
        },
        cache: false,
      };

      apiStudy
        .hitRelayServer(request)
        .then((res: any) => {
          const statsData = res?.data?.data || [];
          if (statsData && statsData.length > 0) {
            const updatedStats = data.map((obj1: any) => {
              const matchingObj = statsData.find((obj2: any) => obj1.name == obj2.name && obj1.studyname == obj2.studyname);
              if (matchingObj) {
                return {
                  ...obj1,
                  cpu: matchingObj?.cpu_p99,
                  memory: matchingObj?.memory_p99,
                  nrequests: matchingObj?.total_request_count,
                  latency: matchingObj?.latency,
                  nerrors: matchingObj?.failure_request_count,
                  nerrorscritical: matchingObj?.log_failure_count,
                  maxCPUReq: matchingObj?.max_cpu_request,
                  maxMemoryReq: matchingObj?.max_memory_request,
                  maxMemoryUsage: matchingObj?.memory_max,
                };
              } else {
                return obj1;
              }
            });
            setData(updatedStats);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('failed to fetch app monitoring- ', err);
        });
    }
    setCompletedRelay(true);
  }, [uniqueAcc]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data == undefined || data.length == 0 || !completedRelay) {
      return;
    }
    listMonitoringWorkloadEventCount();
  }, [completedRelay]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data == undefined || data.length == 0 || !completedEvent) {
      return;
    }
    listMonitoringWorkloadRecommendationCount();
  }, [completedEvent]);

  const listMonitoringWorkloadEventCount = () => {
    const user = getUserSession();
    apiMonitoring
      .listMonitoringWorkloadEventCount(user.tenant?.id as string)
      .then((res) => {
        const workloadEventCountRes = res?.data?.data?.k8s_workloads_cloud_account_monitoring_events_v2?.rows || [];
        if (workloadEventCountRes && workloadEventCountRes.length > 0) {
          const updatedStats = data.map((obj1: any) => {
            const matchingObj = workloadEventCountRes.find(
              (obj2: any) => obj1.accountId == obj2.cloud_account_id && obj1.name == obj2.name && obj1.studyname == obj2.studyname
            );
            if (matchingObj) {
              return {
                ...obj1,
                nevents: matchingObj?.event_count || '-',
              };
            } else {
              return obj1;
            }
          });
          setData(updatedStats);
        }
        setCompleteEvent(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setCompleteEvent(true);
      });
  };

  const listMonitoringWorkloadRecommendationCount = () => {
    const user = getUserSession();
    apiMonitoring
      .listMonitoringWorkloadRecommendationCount(user.tenant?.id as string)
      .then((res) => {
        const workloadRecommendationCountRes = res?.data?.data?.k8s_workloads_cloud_account_monitoring_recommendations_v2?.rows || [];
        if (workloadRecommendationCountRes && workloadRecommendationCountRes.length > 0) {
          const updatedStats = data.map((obj1: any) => {
            const matchingObj = workloadRecommendationCountRes.find(
              (obj2: any) => obj1.accountId == obj2.cloud_account_id && obj1.name == obj2.workload_name && obj1.studyname == obj2.studyname
            );
            if (matchingObj) {
              return {
                ...obj1,
                optimize: matchingObj?.recommendation_count || '-',
              };
            } else {
              return obj1;
            }
          });
          setData(updatedStats);
        }
        setCompletedRelay(false);
        setCompleteEvent(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', flexWrap: 'wrap', margin: '0px -40px' }}>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : !loading && data.length > 0 ? (
        data.map((item, index) => <StudyMonitoringCard data={item} key={index} />)
      ) : errorMessage ? (
        <Typography>{errorMessage}</Typography>
      ) : (
        <Typography>No Data For Monitoring</Typography>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Monitoring;

What I did (Disclaimer: which is NOT working) is I tool two boolean variable that if that variable set then consume a API.
What should be the ideal solution for this situation? Or Even is this correct to use useEffect like this?
